# Integrating gpt2 into unity

Tags: unity, c#, python

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers in integrating [gpt-2](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2) into unity. I've got quite a bit of experience with python, but less with unity. What I'm trying to do is use a pretrained gpt2 model in a unity projects to act as an nps brain. If possible I would also like to be able to export it with everything so the user doesn't have to also go and install libraries.

I'm not quite sure how I would do this, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you know that [Unity has its own machine learning system](https://unity.com/products/machine-learning-agents)?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried using ML Agents before, but was wondering if I could use a more sophisticated system (For complex text conversations) that gpt-2 can do.